# Introduce php code inside arguments of the_title

Tags: php, html, wordpress, arguments

I have this effect: 
http://jsfiddle.net/CgF7a/
that I want to implement for every title in my loop.
My code is:

```
<a class="roll-link" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title('<h7>', '<h7>'); ?></a>
```

and I want to introduce

```
<span data-title="<?php the_title(); ?>"></span>
```

instead of those h7 tags. 
This is not working:

```
<a class="roll-link" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title('<span data-title="<?php the_title(); ?>">', '</span>'); ?></a>
```

How to introduce php code inside the arguments of the_title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you please used this :
please folow below given screenshot for display

[image]